# javascript - use populated array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a one-liner code where I can say the assigning of a variable is to a populated array from a choice of 2 array?

For example:

I'd like:

```
var myArray = ['a','b','c'];
```

The choice is between 2 arrays.

```
var a = [];
var b = ['a','b','c'];
```

So basically if var a is populated, I'd like myArray to = a.
If var a is not populated but var b is populated, myArray = b;
if var a and b are empty, then myArray = [];

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
var myArray = a || b || [];
```

Comment: A conditional operator? `a.length > 0 ? a : b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArray = (a.length) ? a : b;
```

Comment: @JasonAller It would be a good homework for OP though. But no reason to check actually

Comment: no need. b acts as a failover to a and also as the empty double failover.

Comment: actually "it depends". Semantics of `a || b || []` pseudo code and your statement are different

Comment: ahhh, i like the double failover..didnt think of just assigning regardless. Thanks